# How to check for hardware errors with software methods?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

How can I check for bad blocks, bad memory, etc. using only software solutions? I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out `badblocks` if you want a utility that is specifically designed to write/read each LBA of a drive, testing for errors on the way.  `badblocks` offers nondestructive and destructive tests (as noted below it's not overly useful on modern hard drives, though).

If you want to keep up with your drive's SMART parameters, check out `smartctl`.

There's no thorough memory test software that I know of that works while Linux is running, but you can boot into memtest86+ which is a well-respected utility that gives your RAM a good well-rounded test.

Compiling a Linux kernel stresses both the CPU and RAM to a high degree.  If you get errors at random locations during the process (as opposed to reproducible errors) while compiling it could indicate a RAM or CPU problem.

There is also a utility called `stress` that can saturate your system with threads causing CPU usage to stay high if you want to test your CPU.

`lm-sensors`, when configured correctly, will let you look at things like temperatures, fan speeds, and any onboard voltage sensors.

Comment: A note about `badblocks`: I don't see how it could work, since modern drives just redirect bad blocks to spare ones.

Comment: Drives do redirect bad blocks, but these will be reported by SMART. Running badblocks will make sure the drive actually checks all the blocks. Normally, drives do not run self-validation checks.

Answer (score 3):

Take note that you should watch the output of the `dmesg` utility while running memory/CPU stress tests. You'll see nasty error messages from the kernel if there are memory errors, especially if your hardware is equipped with ECC capability.